# angular-cli: ng serve command with config error

Tags: angular-cli

```
Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
    at Class.run (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
    at checkExpressPort.then.then (C:\Users\goldneda\AppData\Roamin
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

Did any one got the same error? What should I do? I'm working with angular-cli, but things just stop working for some reason.

Comment: For the same error, this solution worked for me --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665038/angular-cli-cannot-read-property-config-of-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error, how i solved it by deleting the created app folder and followed the same process again for generating app,

- Delete the created by running ng new  folder
- npm cache clean
- ng new
- cd
- ng serve

Comment: The cause for this in some cases is moving your app to a new directory, and the "hidden files" beginning with a period (such as .angular-cli.json) not being copied over. Either create new "hidden files" or make sure you copy over everything you need.