# Angular CLI: Cannot read property 'config' of null

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Recently upgraded my application from Angular 2.3.0 to Angular 4.0.3. In the process also upgraded angular-cli. If project cloned to a new directory, it is throwing:

> Cannot read property 'config' of null TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'config' of null
>       at Class.run (/Users/hyadav/Documents/projects/web-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/build.js:16:56)
>       at Class.run (/Users/hyadav/Documents/projects/web-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/build.js:143:26)
>       at Class. (/Users/hyadav/Documents/projects/web-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:134:17)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.2.2"
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Cannot read property 'config' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835118/angular-2-cannot-read-property-config-of-null)

Answer (score 17):

**This is a working solution until Angular v5 because inside v6, the location of the file changed to angular.json, and changed also the content**

Create a new file called *.angular-cli.json* and insert:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "PROJECT_NAME"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

You will also find a copy of this json if you create a new project from [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/).

Comment: Just open another ng project with that file present in a separate VS Code window, and simply drag and droped the file to the other ng project where it was missing. The file is at the root level.

Answer (score 9):

Fixed the issue by copying `.angular-cli.json` file to the new directory.

*Per request, more details:*

After creating your project, but prior to moving it to a different directory you will notice a `.angular-cli.json` file was created, visible from the command line via `ls -al`. This file is needed in the root directory of your project.  It should be moved there via `mv .angular-cli.json .` and should be added to source control so others cloning the project have this file.

Comment: can you please explain more detail how you fixed , thanks

Comment: You should copy `.angular-cli.json` file to root folder of Your web application.

Answer (score 4):

i found the solution ! :D

> in my case i moved the project to another directory
>       there is a hidden file called .angular-cli,
>
> > show the hidden file in the old project and copy this file and paste it 
> >         in the new destination.

this is solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

do not forget to install npm packages, 
run `npm i` in root directory

Answer (score 0):

After angular 5, when we create either zip or copy of project, on that time **angular-cli.json file** not included in zip or copy folder and we send this zip or folder to another friend or itself but after install angular project. we run ng serve but unfortunately it given error **cannot read property config of null**

so solve this issue, send also **angular-cli.json** file or you can copy and paste into new project(error project).

***angular-cli.json** = *its **hidden file*** .....must be remembered.