# Issue when running ng build

Tags: angular, npm

I just finished my first Angular 4 project, only utilizing user login. However, when I run `ng build --prod`, I get the following errors:

```
Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined.
The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.

Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli and typescript in
devDependencies, then delete node_modules and package-lock.json (if you have one) and
run npm install again.
```

However, I do the above suggested things, and I still get the same error.  I'm not sure where to begin.

Angular is installed locally on my MacBook Pro, and the API is a backend API call that is all setup.
EDIT EDIT EDIT
Contents of package.json

```
    {
  "name": "angular2-registration-login-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular2-registration-login-example.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.47",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.3",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.60",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2"
  }
}
```

EDIT
After doing the suggested install angular/compiler-cli --save-dev, I get this:

```
ng build --prod

To disable this warning run "ng set --global warnings.typescriptMismatch=false".

Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
    at Class.run (/Users/adamcampbell/Documents/Development/appDir/member/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/build.js:15:56)
    at Class.run (/Users/adamcampbell/Documents/Development/appDir/member/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/build.js:204:26)
    at resolve (/Users/adamcampbell/Documents/Development/appDir/member/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:273:20)
    at Class.validateAndRun (/Users/adamcampbell/Documents/Development/appDir/member/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:251:12)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (/Users/adamcampbell/Documents/Development/appDir/member/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:154:24)
```

Comment: Can you paste your `package.json`.

Comment: @moraya.re - done

Comment: Please check & let me know.

Comment: Is this production code? Can I see it git repo?

Comment: Not production code.  Currently only on local.  Let me see if I can push to git.  Hold on.

Comment: Buddy, you there?

Comment: Refer to this question -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665038/angular-cli-cannot-read-property-config-of-null

Answer (score 0):

Your `package.json` do not have `complier-cli` installed. By running this command -> install it.

`npm install @angular/compiler-cli --save-dev`

Comment: did you install it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, please see above EDIT again.

Comment: @webdevsoup Did you install the typescript version suggested by the command?

Comment: Yes, I did.  And I updated my EDIT.  That is the result after installing the Typescript

Comment: @webdevsoup but I do not see, `@angular/compiler-cli` in your `package.json`

Comment: Updated package.json.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155050/discussion-between-moraya-re-and-webdevsoup).

Answer (score 0):

**You need to copy your .angular-cli.json file to the root folder of your application.**

Trace your error code from line 15 of /node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/build.js

```
const config = config_1.CliConfig.fromProject().config;
```

tracing it further, we find config_1, which is defined on line 9

```
const config_1 = require("../models/config");
```

so we head over to ../models/config.js where we find that fromProject() returns null if it can't find the config file, which points here:

```
exports.CLI_CONFIG_FILE_NAME = '.angular-cli.json';
const CLI_CONFIG_FILE_NAME_ALT = 'angular-cli.json';
```

So if you don't see .angular-cli.json in the root directory of your app, you need to copy it there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this error may come in many situations like.

#### aot/prod build problem

add/install `reflect-metadata` will resolve the problem. Any one facing the issue after angular 4 and have cli may help this.

```
npm i --save-dev reflect-metadata
```

#### you upgraded your node and npm in system

In this case, the node modules are old and it will show error in your project. You can delete node_modules folder and package-lock.josn and do a `npm install` will work.

#### some problem in node module or sync

Just delete node_modules folder and package.json file and do a `npm i` some time resolves the problem.

#### their is problem with cli version, missing dependencies, etc.

Check all the version like node, npm cli etc and see if they are compartable.

This kind of problem mostly happens when we upgrade something.