# Angular 5 dockerized app behind nginx

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, angular5

I am having issues while trying to deploy my Angular 5.1.2 application, basically it works fine in local, but it displays me a blank page on my server, with 404 errors like

> Fail of loading script element which source is ...

For like inline.js, polyfills.js, scripts.js, main.js ...

I think I am doing something wrong with paths, any idea on how to fix this?

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --quiet

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200

CMD [ "npm", "build" ]
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "inspinia",
  "version": "2.7.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --prod -H 0.0.0.0 --live-reload false",
    "build": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "^0.0.21",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
    "jvectormap": "^2.0.4",
    "metismenu": "^2.5.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.3",
    "peity": "^3.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.2",
    "@types/node": "^8.5.2",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.2.2",
    "ts-node": "^4.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0"
  }
}
```

part of my nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name url www.url;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:4200/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    root /var/www/iothings-app;
 }
```

and I run with:

```
docker build -t things-app .
docker run --name iothings-app -p 0.0.0.0:4200:4200 -d things-app
```

Comment: `--base-href=/usr/app` means that your app's url is `http://url/usr/app`. I don't this this would be the case?

Comment: so you suggest to change to `--base-href=/var/www/iothings-app` which is were my code is?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that the base-href setting is the public path of your app. Which url do you want to use for your app? Just  `http://url`, right? If so, you don't need base-href

Comment: I am trying without this parameter indeed, thanks.

Comment: Still the same error while removing this parameter :/

Comment: Is it the angular App returning 404 error or Nginx ? Also try to update this part in you Dockerfile `
`COPY . .` to `COPY . /usr/app`. One more thing is that you made a build then you are trying to `npm start` in the working directory. You should know your build we be in a folder named dist.

Comment: Basically it was displaying a blank page, with the browser development console showing 404 errors while loading .js files, I am trying different Dockerfiles with the ones you provided, but still no success :/

Answer (score 0):

First thing should do is to check your container ID using `docker ps | grep 'things-app'`. Once you have the ID you can use `docker logs ID` and check what is wrong. Second you didnt install Angular CLI but you trying to make a build. I dont think it will work. Bellow is an example I often use to deploy my Angular Apps. But I use http-server. Which one I thing is good enougth to deploy your App. One more thing, if you have not included any Node Server code (MEAN stack) then you dont need at all to run `npm start`. Sometimes I deploy a MEAN stack using expressJs so that I use `npm start` to up my server. Here is my working example :

```
FROM node:alpine
# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install http-server
RUN npm install -g http-server

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Install AngularCLI
npm install -g @angular/cli

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
COPY .angular-cli.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

CMD [ "ng", "build" ]

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["cd", "/usr/src/app/dist", "http-server" ,"-p", "3000"]
```

Finaly you can build and run you container with

```
docker build -t things-app .
docker run --name iothings-app -p 4200:3000 -d things-app
```

Your App will be server over http://SERVER_IP_ADRESS:3000

You dont need to configure nGinx here anymore as you are just serving App over IP and Port

Comment: With this method, I have a page showing "Index of /
Node.js v4.8.7/ ecstatic server running @ localhost:4200"

Comment: Seems you were not clear enough in your question. ecstatic server is a node module so I would like to know if you have any other nodeJs Modules instead of the ones used in your Angular App. I mean, do you have any NodeJs code in your app ?

Comment: I have a lot of modules that were already here (I am using a template), I have updated original question.
Now I am having same error as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665038/angular-cli-cannot-read-property-config-of-null?rq=1), but adding a `.angular-cli.json` file doesn't fix the problem :/